# Counting in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to write in a file('text.txt') all the numbers that are in 's',but from the end to the first number (87654321).
My question is: `mov si,len` = 8 , `dec si` =7 and why `mov dl,byte ptr s+si-1` is correct? `s+si-1` is 6 (0+7-1) and this means the number 5 from 's'(in little-endien).How does it takes the number 8 from 's'?

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    fileName db 'text.txt',0
    s dw '12','34','56','78'

    len equ $-s
    s2 db len dup(?)

    fileHandle dw ?
    openErrorMsg db 'File can not be opened','$'
    writeErrorMsg db 'An error occured when writing','$'
data ends
code segment
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    ;open the file
    openFile:
        mov ah,3dh
        mov al,1
        mov dx,offset fileName
        int 21h
        jc openError
        mov fileHandle,ax

    mov cx,len 
    mov si,len
    dec si
    mov di,0
    jcxz final
    ;make the new array
    formare:
        mov dl,byte ptr s+si-1       ;HERE
        mov s2[di],dl
        inc di
        mov dl,byte ptr s+si
        mov s2[di],dl
        inc di
        sub si,2
        dec cx
        loop formare

    ;write into the file
    writeToFile:
        mov al,0h
        mov ah,40h
        mov bx,fileHandle
        mov cx,len
        mov dx,offset s2
        int 21h
        jc writeError
    jmp final

    openError:
        mov ah,09h
        mov dx,offset openErrorMsg
        int 21h

    writeError:
        mov ah,09h
        mov dx,offset writeErrorMsg
        int 21h 
    final:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: Indexing starts from zero.

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired, but I'm finding your actual question to be very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
s dw '12','34','56','78'
```

---

(**EDIT**: wait a second... NASM will compile these 100% sure in the "reversed" order, like `db '1', '2'`, so strings definitions will make sense. What assembler do you use, if it does compile it literally like numeric value? MASM? And it will compile it as string only when `"` are used? This smell... please, check the memory content in debugger, to avoid some nasty surprise... in the answer below I operate with assumption, that `dw '12'` == `dw 0x3132`, but it seems unlikely to me)

---

compiles into bytes `32 31 34 33 36 35 38 37`, with addresses in table:

```
 addr | hexa byte
------+-----------
 s+0  | 32
 s+1  | 31
 s+2  | 34
 s+3  | 33
 s+4  | 36
 s+5  | 35
 s+6  | 38
 s+7  | 37
```

So "s+6" does indeed point to `'8'`.

Maybe checking the memory content in debugger can help you, if you are not 100% sure how the data were encoded into machine code.

(I didn't check rest of your code, only the data definition, which is IMO answering your question fully?)